# Listagg in a subquery in select clause returns null

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a certain query where the results of the query contain a start_value,step,range kind of values. I want to create a list of all possible values starting from the start_value adding step at each level till the level reaches range.
eg.

```
start_value = 8
step = 1
range = 5
```

Then i want (8,9,10,11,12) as the result.

For this i am using the following code but the listagg part is returning null. Please note that the query with alias main_query will be different in real time and will have multiple rows. Only for demonstration purposes i am using dual there. Also the listagg part will remain the same.

```
    select val,step,rang ,
    (select  listagg(colval) within group(order by colval) from
    (select  val + level*step as colval from dual
    connect by level <= rang+1))
    from
    (select 1 as val , 2 as step , 3 rang from dual) main_query;
```

EDIT :

Many thanks to people who gave a quick response. The problem is there is already a with clause in place which is used by the main_query itself. So according to the solution presented this will be now

```
WITH main_query as (

with query_1 as 
(select ... from ..),
query_2 as 
(select ... from ...),
select val,step,range from 
(select .... from query_1 join query_2 ....)main_query) 
select <values to be created using listagg> from main_query ;
```

I am not sure if this will work .. Please let me know if think it will.

Answer (score 1):

Use `connect by` with `listagg` as following:

```
SQL> WITH MAIN_QUERY AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          8 AS VAL,
  4          1 AS STEP,
  5          5 RANG
  6      FROM
  7          DUAL
  8  )
  9  SELECT
 10      LISTAGG(VAL +((LEVEL - 1) * STEP), ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 11          ORDER BY
 12              LEVEL
 13      ) AS RESULT
 14  FROM
 15      MAIN_QUERY
 16  CONNECT BY
 17      LEVEL <= RANG;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8,9,10,11,12

SQL>
```

For different values:

```
SQL> WITH MAIN_QUERY AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          1 AS VAL,
  4          2 AS STEP,
  5          3 RANG
  6      FROM
  7          DUAL
  8  )
  9  SELECT
 10      LISTAGG(VAL +((LEVEL - 1) * STEP), ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 11          ORDER BY
 12              LEVEL
 13      ) AS RESULT
 14  FROM
 15      MAIN_QUERY
 16  CONNECT BY
 17      LEVEL <= RANG;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,3,5

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

use with statement.

```
   with main as
 (select 8 as start_value , 1 as step , 5 range from dual)
,sub as ( SELECT   LEVEL   AS colval
                      FROM main 
                CONNECT BY LEVEL  < start_value+range*step
  )
,sub2 as(
select * from
sub,main
where colval>=start_value
)
select listagg(colval,',') within group(order by colval)  from
sub2
```